# Answering Amen after Yihyu Leratzon

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

If someone, for some reason, **forgot to say the 1st Yihyu Leratzon** during Shemoneh Esrei and started Elokai Netzor, is he allowed to answer Amen to Kadish as he would be having recited the 1st Yihyu Leratzon?

To be more specific, if the 1st Yihyu Leratzon concludes the official part of Shemoneh Esrei and someone did not say it or skipped it, would he be considered to still be in Shemone Esrei until he finishes Elokai Netzor and recites the 2nd Yihyu Leratzon?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%91

Answer (score 3):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([18:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.18.14?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) says that while it is preferable to say יִהְיוּ לְרָצוֹן first, **one may interrupt Elokai Netzor to answer those things one is allowed to answer during the non-interrupt sections of Tefila**, like Amen after HaE-il Hakodosh, and Shomei'a Tefila, Amen-Yehei of Kadish, the first 2 responses of Kedusha, and Borchu, even if one has not yet said יִהְיוּ לְרָצוֹן.

> אֲבָל בִּתְפִלַּת אֱלֹהַי נְצֹר מֻתָּר לְהַפְסִיק לִדְבָרִים שֶׁמַּפְסִיקִין בְּאֶמְצַע פֶּרֶק שֶׁל בִּרְכוֹת קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וּקְרִיאַת שְׁמַע. לְעֵיל סִימָן ט"ז. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם, אִם אֶפְשָׁר לוֹ יֹאמַר תְּחִלָּה יִהְיוּ לְרָצוֹן וְגוֹ', וְאִם אֶפְשָׁר עוֹד יִפְסַע גַּם כֵּן גּ' פְּסִיעוֹת. (ק"ד כק"ב)

> However, when saying: Elokai Netzor, interruptions are permitted for those things for which you may interrupt in the middle of a section of the berachos of Shema, or the Shema itself. (See [Chapter 16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.16.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he).) Nevertheless if possible you should first recite: Yiheyu Leratzon and if there is still time, you should also take three steps backward.